# Insert space after multiple matching strings

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

My original file is below......

```
awk test1(GROUP)Xroot(USER)X
cat test1(GROUP)Ntest2(GROUP)Xroot(USER)X
chmod test2(GROUP)Xtest3(GROUP)Xroot(USER)N
chown test2(GROUP)Xtest3(GROUP)Xroot(USER)X
crontab test1(GROUP)Xroot(USER)Xtest2(GROUP)X
```

Looking for an output as below...

```
awk test1(GROUP)X root(USER)X
cat test1(GROUP)N test2(GROUP)X root(USER)X
chmod test2(GROUP)X test3(GROUP)X root(USER)N
chown test2(GROUP)X test3(GROUP)X root(USER)X
crontab test1(GROUP)X root(USER)X test2(GROUP)X
```

I need to search for anything with (USER)N, (USER)X, (GROUP)X, (GROUP)N and add a space just after that so that it will be delimited from next string. I tried many combinations with sed but not sure whats wrong.

Comment: I dont know why the data is pasted like that. awk, cat, chmod, chown, crontab...they all are on next line.

Comment: So add a newline between the lines manually.

Comment: I've rolled back to the last good version of the original question. Please do not modify one question into another, since that makes any answers below incorrect automatically. Answers *are not just for you*, they are for future readers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/(\((USER|GROUP)\)[XN])(.)/\1 \3/g' file
awk test1(GROUP)X root(USER)X
cat test1(GROUP)N test2(GROUP)X root(USER)X
chmod test2(GROUP)X test3(GROUP)X root(USER)N
chown test2(GROUP)X test3(GROUP)X root(USER)X
crontab test1(GROUP)X root(USER)X test2(GROUP)X
```